# how to update string concatenation in postgres sql with existing value

Tags: postgresql

I have a reports table with value as shown below

```
id  reportIdList
1   123, 124, 125
2   123, 124, 125
3   123, 124, 125, 127
4   123, 124, 125, 127
```

I need some help with sql to add additional value as in

```
id  reportIdList
1   123, 124, 125, *126*
2   123, 124, 125, *126*
3   123, 124, 125, *126*, 127
4   123, 124, 125, *126*, 127
```

Currently I have a way to update

`update reports set reportIdList = reportIdList || ',126';`

But this would update the table as shown below:

```
  id  reportIdList

  1   123, 124, 125, *126*
  2   123, 124, 125, *126*
  3   123, 124, 125, 127, *126*
  4   123, 124, 125, 127, *126*
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated lists to begin with. Do you have a chance to fix your data model?

Comment: The table has other values as comma separated lists, but always open to hear suggestions, please do let me know thanks

Comment: Create a properly normalized one-to-many relationship with a foreign key (and probably a unique index) and this gets as easy as `insert into ...`

Comment: Thanks, how about storing the data as json type

Comment: @AnoopN Yes, using a postgres or json array would make it easier, but still not as easy as a proper relational design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a function to deal with your bad design:

```sql
create or replace function add_element(p_input text, p_add text)
  returns text
as
$$
  select string_agg(x::text, ','  order by x)
  from (
    select trim(nullif(x,''))
    from unnest(string_to_array(p_input, ',')) as e(x)
    union 
    select p_add
  ) t(x);
$$
language sql;
```

Then you can do:

```
update the_table
  set reportidlist = add_element(reportidlist, 126);
```

---

But you should really fix your data model and stop storing comma separated strings.

Comment: The union by default changes the order of the values..and i am sorry in my example i have used only integers but my table report ids are alphanumeric as in the value is like ```5811957ba681,eab24d87bb9e,b4e01c134c67``` and i wanted to add ```187d19223303```. Any help with these data??

Comment: @AnoopN: that's why the `string_agg()` uses `order by` - but with text values like that this won't help.

Comment: ya the order is all messed up :). Any other way to update this comma separated strings??

Comment: Having comma separated values in a single column is a bad idea to begin with. But making the order of those elements important, is even worse. If you normalize that to a proper one-to-many relationship, the "many" table doesn't have an order either

Comment: thanks, yes, i am working to change the design. Hopefully will be able to correct it. Thanks for your help